# What is this binary relation called?

Tags: relations

Let $\alpha$ be a binary relation over $X$, i.e., $\alpha\subseteq X^2$.

What is that name for the binary relation $\beta_{\alpha}$ over $X$ defined by

- $a\mathrel{\beta_{\alpha}} b$ iff $a\mathrel{\alpha} b$ and $b\mathrel{\alpha} a$?

For example, if $\alpha$ is the specialization relation on a topological space, then $\beta_{\alpha}$ is the topologically-indistinguishable equivalence relation.

- What is the name for $\beta_{\alpha}$ given $\alpha$?
- $\beta_{\alpha}$ is the ... of $\alpha$?

Comment: maximal symmetric subrelation?

Comment: @Greg Martin I am just wondering if it has a common name.

Answer (score 2):

In the special case when $\alpha$ is a preorder (such as your specialization relation), $\beta_\alpha$ is an equivalence relation, sometimes called the induced equivalence relation of $\alpha$. But this name may not be that standard.

Comment: Thanks, That is exactly the scenario I am faced with, $\alpha$ is a preorder, $\beta_\alpha$ is the equivalence relation we must factor by to get an order. Does it have a name well-known name...

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the most common application, but I have taken a class in which this strategy (modding out by the equivalence relation) is performed several times without a name... Perhaps people think it's too easy to have a name?

Comment: In what I am doing, the $\beta_\alpha$ has become the "object of interest" so would be nice to have a name.